# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: update or delete on table when deleting a record

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql

I use django and postgress and have a very odd exception.
I have a model object called ProductModel (with upc as a unique_id).
This is how the model looks like:

```
class ProductModel(models.Model):

def __str__(self):
    return self.clean_name + " " + str(self.product_upc)

product_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
product_upc = models.CharField(max_length=300, primary_key=True)
official_price = models.DecimalField(default=0, decimal_places=5, max_digits=10)
mrsp = models.DecimalField(default=0, decimal_places=5, max_digits=10)
last_seen = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
clean_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
```

unfortunately (as I understand now) at the begining of times I made a mistake and created a class called product that inherits the ProductModel - this class has some regular methods nothing fancy.

```
class Product(ProductModel):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.create_clean_name()
    self.img_list = []
    self.scraped_content = ""
    self.specs = {}
```

Now, I was sure that this class has nothing to do with the db and the db doesnt aware of its existence - but now When I try to delete some product records using this command:

```
p = ProductModel.objects.all().filter(last_seen__month__lt=4,product_name__contains='a')
    p.delete()
```

I get the following error -

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: update or delete on table "my_app_productmodel" violates foreign key constraint "f64b7bfb6c6019a35bf6b81e4125240f" on table "my_app_product"
        DETAIL:  Key (product_upc)=(852896336240) is still referenced from table "my_app_product"
```

And in this point I got totally lost and confused what the h*** is table "my_app_product" - why it exists??
I went to my PostgreSQL and found out that this table is really exists.
I'd like to understand how does it work and how I delete records in this situation.
ohh and one more detail - as I try to delete my records via django admin I manage to do it without any problems.

Thanks to the kind helper.

Comment: Django created an implicit `OneToOneField` between your two models, as it is described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). I think you have to remove your `Product` model and its corresponding table in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you actually did: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance

Subclassing a model (that is not defined as abstract) will create a new table called Product that has a OneToOneField to ProductModel pk which is `product_upc`. You are trying to delete a ProductModel which has a reference to Product table, this is why you get the error.

Depending on how you use that Product class I suggest to just change its superclass to `object` and run `makemigrations` to remove the table, since you don't actually need it.

Comment: Thanks for your help but, I didnt understand. I need this functionality. I need to be able to inherit a the productModel because I have a bunch of methods etc in the product class. Is there any way around this annoying problem?

Comment: "my_app_product" exists because you defined Product as a subclass of ProductModel. If you check the columns from "my_app_product" you should see a FK ending with "_ptr" that was created automatically by django. Since you don't need "my_app_product" you just need to change the Product class to no longer subclass ProductModel and create migration that will remove that table.

Comment: yes but then I cant save the product . now I understand that I have a bad design. but as a first aid I need to find a way to remove a bunch of products but keep the functionality of the product class. I use this class in order to save the products to the db(it inherits the method save() )

Comment: If all your code depends on Product class then change your save() method to call ProductModel save method. Otherwise move save() method to ProductModel itself

Comment: override save method sounds like a good Idea thanks!. The only thing that I don't understand-I have two tables containing my products how I remove products from both of them?

Comment: Your "my_app_product" contains only a column, just have a look at that table. To remove that table you need to make Product class as standalone (not subclass ProductModel anymore) and run 'makemigrations'. But I guess you have methods in Product class that does stuff in behalf of ProductModel, so you need to refactor that part (as you do with save method).

Comment: thanks I changed the product to inherit object instead of product model. Then migrated removed all the rows i needed to remove. And reverted all the changes I made and migrated again.